# How come my Function Will Not Work When Calling .js File in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys i've been getting really frustrated with the code..i am trying to call a .js file on my html but its currently not working :( i know that the code and everything is right but it will not perform the function. Are you guys able to see if my code is correct?

This is my HTML Code.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction1()"> Press Me!! </button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Test2.js"></script>
```

This is my JS Code that i am trying to call on html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head> 
<title> Lab 4 - Task 2.2</title>
<script type = "text/javaScript"> </script>
<p id="demo"</p>
<button onclick="myFunction1()"> Press </button>
<script>
function myFunction1()
{
var x;
var number1=prompt("Please Enter a Number", "");
var number2=prompt("Please Enter a Second Number", "");
var number3=prompt("Please Enter a Third Number", "");
var number4=prompt("Please Enter a Fourth Number", "");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= Math.max (number1, number2, number3, number4);
}
</script>
</body>
```

The code works when i run it as a html file on the web-browser, but when i convert the file to .js it does not work when calling from HTML. Am i doing something wrong here?

Assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: <p id="demo"</p> should be <p id="demo"></p>

Comment: What do you mean by *convert the file to .js*? You shouldn't have any HTML in the JavaScript file.

Comment: The only part of that which should be in your .js file is the stuff inside the `<script>...</script>` block (and do not include the `<script>` tag itself).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a `.js` file, *all* of the code in that file must be javascript. You would want to create the function like so:

```
function myFunction1()
{
var x;
var number1=prompt("Please Enter a Number", "");
var number2=prompt("Please Enter a Second Number", "");
var number3=prompt("Please Enter a Third Number", "");
var number4=prompt("Please Enter a Fourth Number", "");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= Math.max (number1, number2, number3, number4);
}
```

**And then, you would include the script in your HTML document**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_script.js"></script>
```

And from here you will be able to use the function as if it were part of your HTML page.

Comment: Thank you for that response was really helpful

Comment: @user1618490 Please make sure you accept an answer, doesn't need to be mine but it's important to close the question if it has been solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> This is my JS Code that i am trying to call on html

That's an HTML document. A `.js` file should contain only JS. It shouldn't even have `<script>` tags in it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was running on Webmatrix. so i had to change the path of .js file lik this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Test2.js"></script>
```

O and .js file should only contain javascript code:

```
function myFunction1()
{
var x;
var number1=prompt("Please Enter a Number", "");
var number2=prompt("Please Enter a Second Number", "");
var number3=prompt("Please Enter a Third Number", "");
var number4=prompt("Please Enter a Fourth Number", "");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= Math.max (number1, number2, number3, number4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following:

1. Check if HTML, JS files are in the same directory or specify correct location.
2. JS file does not need any HTML headers.
3. Include your JS file in the head portion of your HTML doc.
4. Remove script and other tags from JS file.

(For a JS file you don't need to even add the file type just src is suffcient).